# AngularJs Save data.d.results in var result =

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, sharepoint

Is It possible to save/replace data from the $ HTTP ( data.d.results ) to var Result =  ?

```
 .factory('ContactService', [function () {
      var factory = {};

      factory.getContacts = function () {
        return contactList;
      }

      // contact list, usually would be a separate database
      var contactList = [
        {id: 0, name: 'Ned Stark', email: 'ned@winterfell.com', phone: '123-456-7890', url: 'www.google.com', notes: 'Winter is coming.'},

        ];

      return factory;
```

example above works!
but I want to put data.d.results with the result in

> Var contactlist =

```
$http({

method: 'GET',

url: 'URL', 

headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

$scope.InProgs = data.d.results;

})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should add a `set` method in your `service`

Add the method

```
factory.setContacts = function (contacts) {
    contactList = contacts;
}
```

and call it in your `http success` function like this

```
$http({

method: 'GET',

url: 'URL', 

headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }

}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

$scope.InProgs = data.d.results;

ContactService.setContacts(data.d.results); //the call of the setter

})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Your service should be

```
.factory('ContactService', [function () {
  var factory = {};

  factory.getContacts = function () {
    return contactList;
  }

  factory.setContacts = function (contacts) {
    contactList = contacts;
  }

  // contact list, usually would be a separate database
  var contactList = [
    {id: 0, name: 'Ned Stark', email: 'ned@winterfell.com', phone: '123-456-7890', url: 'www.google.com', notes: 'Winter is coming.'},

    ];

  return factory;
```

**Reminder: Don't forget to import your service in the controler**